# How to use where in @query in room library in Android

Tags: android, android-room

I am using Room persistence library in my to access DB data.

In my dao class i write queries as

```
@Query("SELECT id, uniqueId, number, user_id, first_name, last_name,
           image FROM CONTACTS WHERE status != stts")
    abstract fun allContacts(stts: Int): DataSource.Factory<Int, Contact>
```

This is fine . But what if i have to compare status to some constant value ,
like status != Constant.STATUS_FAILED

Here 
val STATUS_FAILED = 5 defined in Constant File.

How do i use it in query. I know i can just pass it in the allContacts method as parameter and use like status != :stts . But i do not want that.
Is there any way to use it directly like status != Constant.STATUS_FAILED.

I do not see any example on https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data

Answer (score 3):

You must add this : in @Query

> @Query("Select * from Workout where nameTypeTraining= :nameTypeTraining")

- getAllWorkout(String nameTypeTraining);

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
@Query("SELECT id, uniqueId, number, user_id, first_name, last_name,
       image FROM CONTACTS WHERE status != " + Constant.STATUS_FAILED)
abstract fun allContacts(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Contact>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String formatting to input the constant.

```
@Query(String.format("SELECT id, uniqueId, number, user_id, first_name, last_name,
           image FROM CONTACTS WHERE status != %s", Constants.STATUS_FAILED))
    abstract fun allContacts(stts: Int): DataSource.Factory<Int, Contact>
```

Hopefully that helps!